# Catching an exception RESTEASY004645: templateValues entry was null

Tags: java, service, mockito, keycloak, spring-boot-test

I am in the process of creating tests for AdminClientService, which whould create users into Keycloak database. In the main processing it works as it should, but while creating tests i bumped into this exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: RESTEASY004645: templateValues entry was null
        at com.springboot.services.KeycloakAdminClientServiceTest.createKeycloakUserTest(KeycloakAdminClientServiceTest.java:80)
```

Here is the test, I am currently running:

```
@SpringBootTest
public class KeycloakAdminClientServiceTest {
    @Value("${keycloak.auth-server-url}")
    public String serverUrl;
    @Value("${keycloak.realm}")
    public String realm;
    @Value("${keycloak.resource}")
    public String clientId;
    @Value("${keycloak.credentials.secret}")
    public String clientSecret;
    
    // @Mock
    // KeycloakProvider kcProvider = Mockito.mock(KeycloakProvider.class);
    
    // @InjectMocks
    // 
    
    // @BeforeEach
    // void setMockOutput() {
    //     //when(helloService.get()).thenReturn("Hello Mockito");
    //     Mockito.when(kcProvider.getInstance()).thenReturn(KeycloakBuilder.builder()
    //         .realm(realm)
    //         .serverUrl(serverUrl)
    //         .clientId(clientId)
    //         .clientSecret(clientSecret)
    //         .grantType(OAuth2Constants.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS)
    //         .build());
    // }
    KeycloakProvider kcProvider;
    KeycloakAdminClientService kcAdminClientService;
    
    @BeforeEach
    void createKeycloakProvider() {
        kcProvider = new KeycloakProvider();
        kcProvider.setServerUrl(serverUrl);
        kcProvider.setRealm(realm);
        kcProvider.setClientId(clientId);
        kcProvider.setClientSecret(clientSecret);
        kcAdminClientService = new KeycloakAdminClientService(kcProvider);
    }
    
    @Test
    public void createKeycloakUserTest(){
        Integer generatedInteger = (int) ((Math.random() * (9999999 - 1000000)) + 1000000);
        String generatedString = generatedInteger.toString();

        CreateUserRequest createUserRequest = new CreateUserRequest();
        createUserRequest.setUsername("admin_client_username_" + generatedString);
        createUserRequest.setPassword("admin_client_password");
        createUserRequest.setEmail("admin_client_email_" + generatedString + "@gmail.com");
        createUserRequest.setFirstname("admin_client_firstname_" + generatedString);
        createUserRequest.setLastname("admin_client_lastname_" + generatedString);
        
        kcAdminClientService.createKeycloakUser(createUserRequest);
        
        UsersResource usersResource = kcProvider.getInstance()
            .realm(kcAdminClientService.realm).users();
        List<UserRepresentation> userRepresentation = usersResource
            .search("admin_client_email_" + generatedString + "@gmail.com");
        assertNotNull(userRepresentation);
        assertEquals("admin_client_firstname_" + generatedString,
            userRepresentation.get(0).getFirstName());

    }

}
```

Here is the service:

```
@Service
public class KeycloakAdminClientService {
    @Value("${keycloak.realm}")
    public String realm;

    private final KeycloakProvider kcProvider;


    public KeycloakAdminClientService(KeycloakProvider keycloakProvider) {
        this.kcProvider = keycloakProvider;
    }

    public Response createKeycloakUser(CreateUserRequest user) {
        UsersResource usersResource = kcProvider.getInstance().realm(realm).users();
        CredentialRepresentation credentialRepresentation = createPasswordCredentials(
            user.getPassword());

        UserRepresentation kcUser = new UserRepresentation();
        kcUser.setUsername(user.getEmail());
        kcUser.setCredentials(Collections.singletonList(credentialRepresentation));
        kcUser.setFirstName(user.getFirstname());
        kcUser.setLastName(user.getLastname());
        kcUser.setEmail(user.getEmail());
        kcUser.setEnabled(true);
        kcUser.setEmailVerified(false);
        Response response = usersResource.create(kcUser);

        return response;

    }

    private static CredentialRepresentation createPasswordCredentials(String password) {
        CredentialRepresentation passwordCredentials = new CredentialRepresentation();
        passwordCredentials.setTemporary(false);
        passwordCredentials.setType(CredentialRepresentation.PASSWORD);
        passwordCredentials.setValue(password);
        return passwordCredentials;
    }
}
```

and the KeycloakProvider:

```
@Configuration
@Getter
@Setter
public class KeycloakProvider {
    @Value("${keycloak.auth-server-url}")
    public String serverUrl;
    @Value("${keycloak.realm}")
    public String realm;
    @Value("${keycloak.resource}")
    public String clientId;
    @Value("${keycloak.credentials.secret}")
    public String clientSecret;

    private static Keycloak keycloak = null;

    public KeycloakProvider() {
    }

    public Keycloak getInstance() {
        if (keycloak == null) {

            return KeycloakBuilder.builder()
                    .realm(realm)
                    .serverUrl(serverUrl)
                    .clientId(clientId)
                    .clientSecret(clientSecret)
                    .grantType(OAuth2Constants.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS)
                    .build();
        }
        return keycloak;
    }

    public KeycloakBuilder newKeycloakBuilderWithPasswordCredentials(
        String username,
        String password) {
        return KeycloakBuilder.builder()
                .realm(realm)
                .serverUrl(serverUrl)
                .clientId(clientId)
                .clientSecret(clientSecret)
                .username(username)
                .password(password);
    }

    public JsonNode refreshToken(String refreshToken) throws UnirestException {
        String url = serverUrl + "/realms/" + realm + "/protocol/openid-connect/token";
        return Unirest.post(url)
                .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                .field("client_id", clientId)
                .field("client_secret", clientSecret)
                .field("refresh_token", refreshToken)
                .field("grant_type", "refresh_token")
                .asJson().getBody();
    }
}
```

I tried using Mockito for this problem, but realized it won't work, as I wanted it to.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it myself, instead of that code above you just should write it like that, should've wrote @Autowired.

```
@Autowired
KeycloakProvider kcProvider;
@Autowired
KeycloakAdminClientService kcAdminClientService;
```

and it would solve all the problems)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).